# Drag from Drive to computer

Tags: google-drive

I create an Electron App for generating qrcode. The user create a form and add datas by input text or file. For input file, he get files from google drive (I implement google drive REST api).

But for the user it's more easy to drag file from google drive and drop it in the form for datas, instead of getting datas by using input files.

I want to know if it's possible to drag files FROM google drive and drop it TO my Document folder for example ?

Not from my computer to Drive, I mean from Drive to my computer

Comment: Forgive me if I sound rude, but why don't you just try?

Comment: Also, what’s the context? Having Drive open in your browser? Or are you referring to some client/sync software?

Comment: Excuse my English
I create an electron app in which i upload document from google drive. So instead of uploading document i wanted to know if it's possible to drag and drop document directly

Comment: So you have an Electron app. That still doesn’t explain how exactly Google Drive comes into play. What do you mean by “upload”. Please just explain what the user currently has to do to get their document from Google Drive into your application. [Add this information to your question.](https://superuser.com/posts/1287776/edit) Don’t write it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Drive client](https://www.google.com.au/drive/download/) for Windows (and maybe Mac OS). This allows you to sync folders on your computer with your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot drag and drop from google drive's graphical user interface to windows explorer graphical user interface.

Comment: Before anyone else downvotes, I would like to point out that when I posted this answer, the question was as follows 

"I want to know if it's possible to drag files FROM google drive and drop it TO my Document folder for example ?
Not from my computer to Drive, I mean from Drive to my computer"

And so I tried to unambiguously state that you can't D&D from Drive online GUI to windows explorer GUI, which is a true statement, and I think it's a fair answer to the question posed at the time.

Comment: Your comment is quite  confusing.. You comment that the question "was as follows", then you quote something that is still in the question. The question STILL says "I want to know if it's possible to drag files FROM google drive and drop it TO my Document folder for example ? Not from my computer to Drive, I mean from Drive to my computer""

Comment: @barlop I don't think it is confusing, when I posted my answer, the bit in quotes was the entirety of the question. The question was as followed.